# Highchart - Tooltip prevents click

Tags: highcharts, bar-chart

I have a stacked bar chart. there is a problem with the tooltips. One cannot click an item hidden by a tooltip. The simple solution is to remove the tooltip - but it's useful so I would rather keep it.

Ideally I would like to be able to click the underlying part of the chart through the tool tip. Another solution I thought of would be to have the tool tip move away as the mouse approaches it.

jsfiddle.net/MAYO/cm5roecm/2/

Comment: How would you ideally have it function?

Comment: How about `tooltip.followPointer: true`?

Comment: Dude! That was it. Thx. Make it a comment I'll vote you up. I saw it and didn't think anything of it.

Comment: Good to hear. My pleasure!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tooltip.followPointer` set to `true` to prevent the cursor from ever overlapping the tooltip.

Example code: ([updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cm5roecm/3/)):

```
tooltip: {
    followPointer: true
}
```